# Co-ordinate Parabola Circle Contained in it; Difference in maximum and minimum possible radius

Tags: circles, conic-sections

If the Difference of radii of larget and smallest Circle passing through the focus of Parabola $$Y^2=4x$$ and toughing parabola in at least one point is
My Approach
Let Circle be $$C: (x-a)^2+y^2=r^2$$
Since it passes through focus of parabola:(1,0) 
=> $$r^2=(1-a)^2$$
$$C: (x-a)^2+y^2=(1-a)^2$$
Solving for Parabola and Circle; putting $$Y^2=4x$$ in circle equation
$$(x-a)^2+4x=(1-a)^2
=> x^2+x(4-2a)+2a-1
$$
Since the Circle will touch the parabola at only ONE POINT; the equation's Discriminant = 0
 Which gives a=1,5 which gives r=0,4 
r=4 is correct 
but r=0 means point circle which doesn't touches the parabola; where did I go wrong ?
and the answer to the question is 7/2

Comment: You try to find the largest and smallest Circle passing through the focus of Parabola? There are infinitely many circles passing through that point. What other conditions have to be satisfied?

Comment: As soon as you make the statement that $r^2=(1-a)^2$ you need to qualify it by saying that $a\neq 1$ otherwise $r=0$. The smallest circle is clearly the one with the vertex and the focus as opposite ends of the diameter, giving $r=\frac 12$ thus providing the answer you are looking for.

Comment: @DavidQuinn That is correct; I plotted the graph and it fits; but my doubt is why doesn't it comes in solution as r=4 comes; or how do i know that the circle with r=1/2 will not cut the parabola in between 0<x<1 ; The main doubt is why doesn't r=1/2 comes as solution